# Install cron from console

Tags: cron

Is there any way to do the `crontab -e`, save and exit from vim from the console directly?

I realised that in order to make cron work with [Docker](https://www.docker.com), I should do `crontab -e` and save and exit, that is the way that makes it works, so I was thinking of adding it to a script init to do it automatically on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on your question; what do you mean by this:

> …save and exit from vim from the console directly?

Also not 100% clear on the [Docker](https://www.docker.com) aspect of this.

But regardless you generally do not have to use `crontab -e` to edit a crontab.  You can simply set the same values in a text file and then have them loaded into the crontab. For example, let’s say you have a text file name `my_crontab.txt` with these contents:

```
*/5 * * * * do_something.sh
```

Which would run the script `do_something.sh` every 5 minutes, then you could load that text file into the crontab with this command:

```
crontab my_crontab.txt
```

And then if you view the crontab after that command is run like this:

```
crontab -l
```

You will see the same content as if you were editing it more directly via `crontab -e`.

Answer (score 0):

Set vim as your default terminal editor
by adding the following to either
Linux .bashrc or Mac .profile
depending on your platform:

export EDITOR=vim

Save the .bashrc or .profile, quit and restart terminal.

Then... when you type at the command line:

crontab -e

vim will open allowing you to edit and save normally.